# Is it possible to understand Allah by logic?

Tags: quran

Verse 6:101 uses logic to show that Allah has no son.

> [He is] Originator of the heavens and the earth. How could He have a
> son when He does not have a companion [i.e., wife] and He created all
> things? And He is, of all things, Knowing. ([6] Al-An'am : 101)

How does this verse relate to the idea of omnipotence? Is it possible to understand Allah by logic?

Answer (score -1):

Allah is at the same time, **The Manifest** and **The Hidden**

> He is the First and the Last, the Manifest and the Hidden, and He is
> All-Knowing of everything. [Quran 57:3](https://quran.com/al-hadid/3)

Evidence for there to be a creator is very clear if one has good knowledge of science.

> There is no god but He: That is the witness of Allah, His angels, and
> **those endued with knowledge, standing firm on justice**. There is no god
> but He, the Exalted in Power, the Wise. [Quran 3:18](https://quran.com/3/18)

For example, the fundamental constants in physics are so tuned, so that life can flourish in earth. If the values of any of these constant is little different than how much it is now, it will be impossible for life to exist in this world. You can read more about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_universe

> You see the mountains and think them firmly fixed. But they shall pass
> away as the clouds pass away. **Such is the work of God, who has ordered
> all things to perfection:** He is fully aware of what you do. [Quran
> 27:88](https://quran.com/an-naml/88)

Also the universe is filled with information, like information inside gene of every species, information of celestial bodies like their size, position, properties.. All these information cannot come from nothingness.

> And how many a sign within the heavens and earth do they pass over
> while they, therefrom, are turning away. [Quran 12:105](https://quran.com/12/105)